How to detect for horizontal collisions using character controller
How do I check for wall collisions in unity with the character controller component?  I am aware that OnControllerColliderHit exists but it only checks for collisions between the floor and player, and I want to check for collisions between the walls and the player, as well as be able to get the name of the wall game object it touched.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can add a tag on each wall and then use the method OnCollisionEnter() inside your character controller and check with what object you collide.
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    var collidedObject = collision.gameObject;

    if (collidedObject.CompareTag("Wall"))
    {
        var objectName = collidedObject.name;
    }
}

If your game is a 2D you can use this method OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) which deals with 2D collisions, but remember you need to also add a collider component on your wall objects too.
I would suggest you to create a prefab for your wall so you don't have to manually add the tag on each wall.

Hello and thank you for responding, but unfortunately this does not work for me.  I added the following code:
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
Debug.Log(collision.gameObject.name);
}
and it does not print anything when I touch the object.  I have colliders on both game objects and is trigger is set to false on both.

Are you working on a 2d or 3d game?

I am working on a 3D game
